# Is there any way to use method inside of attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I have attribute and it has enum property. I'm using it in method. Here is my code

```
 public class MyAttibute : Attribute
{
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

And using of attribute

```
 class MyEnums
    {
        public const MyEnum MainEnum = (MyEnum)1;
        public const MyEnum SimpleEnum = (MyEnum)2;
    }

    [MyAttibute(MyEnum = MyEnums.MainEnum)]
    void MyMethod()
    {

    }
```

I have another class that contains number which MyEnums constants were casted

```
     class MyNumbers
    {
        public const int MainEnum = 1;
        public const int SimpleEnum = 2;
    }
```

So, I created method GetEnumFromNumber:

```
     MyEnum GetEnumFromNumber(int number)
    {
        return (MyEnum)number;
    }
```

But I can't use this in attribute. Is it possible to use MyNumbers class instead of creating MyEnums class?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but do you want to have something like this: [MyAttibute(MyEnum = (MyEnum)MyNumbers.MainEnum)] ?

Comment: You haven't really explained your goal. You need to assign an enum value to the attribute dynamically at runtime? Regardless, there is no reason for `MyEnums` nor `MyNumbers`, just delete those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `MyEnum` members directly to your attibute:

```
[MyAttibute(MyEnum = MyEnum.Main)]
```

and you can have any logic inside your attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly MyEnum myEnum;

    public MyAttribute(int number)
    {
        this.myEnum = GetEnumFromNumber(number);
        // OR: this.myEnum = (MyEnum)number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using API and can't change attribute class